# Redirection with $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] and using header()

Tags: php

is it possible to do this , im trying to validate a form then, it will redirect using header() if TRUE.. but it seems not to be working? or my method is completely wrong ?

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email = $_POST["clientEmail"];

    if ($email != $sentEmailClients) {
        echo 'Please enter a valid email';
    } else {

        $newURL = "http://www.myurl.com";
        header('Location: ' . $newURL);
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? If not, output some debug info.

Comment: Your title says something about `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Does that have anything to do with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi It seems that Your outermost `if condition` is not working thats why your `header` `function` is not working i just tried this and it woks fine. That means either your first  `if condition` is `false` or either second if condition becomes `true` every time just try to `echo` your values before checking them.

```
<?php
if (1) {
    $email = $_POST["clientEmail"];

    if (0) {
        echo 'Please enter a valid email';
    } else {

        $newURL = "http://www.google.com";
        header('Location: ' . $newURL);
    }
}
```

check this `print_r($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]);` is POST or not and

```
$email != $sentEmailClients true or false
```

Comment: it worked! thanks, my problem was the if condition $email != $sentEmailClients i've changed it to email === $sentEmailClients

Answer (score 1):

Give us more details about what actually happens when you run your code. You're likely facing one of the following problems:

1. You're using `header()` after you've already sent output to the browser. Headers must be sent before any other output. Check out [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). If you change that line with `die('redirecting')` and that text shows up, then this is your problem.
2. Request method is not `POST`. Add `die($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`. If something other than `POST` is printed, then this is your problem.
3. `$_POST['clientEmail']` is not set, or is not equal to `$email`
4. `$email` is not what you expect (where does it come from?)
5. `$sentEmailClients` is not what you expect (where does it come from?)

Basically, "why doesn't it work?" is not a good question because it doesn't give us much info with which to help you. Be more specific about what is happening.

Show enough of your code that we understand the origin of the variables you use.